# Is there a bluetooth adaptor that can take audio in via cable and transmit to headsets via bluetooth?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, stereo

Sorry if the title is confusing and that is why I have created a little diagram. Basically I am trying to connect my Bluetooth headsets to my computer but since, I don't have native Bluetooth device on my computer, and have no way to install new Bluetooth dongle (disabled by admin), I thought if I can simply connect my regular audio out cable to a standalone Bluetooth device, that can transmit the audio to any Bluetooth device..

If there is a device/transmitter that can do that for me, what are they called, and can someone please suggest me any?

[image: Here is what I am trying to achieve:]

Comment: Sorry I don't mean to be rude, but I specifically mentioned that I have no way to install a BT adapter on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Cheap and cheerful way without using bluetooth headsets - All you need is some headsets that have an FM radio, and one of those small bluetooth transmitters that are used in a car that have a headphone jack - Plug this into the computer, tune in the headsets and whatever audio is played through the laptop will come out via the headsets. If you can't install a bluetooth adapter on the computer this is the easiest way I can think of.

Comment: Transmitter type http://www.argos.co.uk/static/Product/partNumber/1069507.htm

Comment: Cheap headsets http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/221772492231?lpid=122&chn=ps&googleloc=1006618&poi=&campaignid=207297426&device=c&adgroupid=13585920426&rlsatarget=pla-131843280786&adtype=pla&crdt=0

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but really would like to first explore if I can use my existing bluetooth headsets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are now many cheap options for converting 3.5mm analog audio to Bluetooth.

Many of the options have a physical switch to change between "transmit" mode and "receive" mode, which controls whether the audio comes in on Bluetooth and goes out over 3.5mm, or comes in over 3.5mm and goes out over Bluetooth.

If you wanted *duplex* audio (a headset with a microphone, with audio going both directions simultaneously), you might be out of luck - I've been looking and haven't yet found.  But it sounds like what you want is "simplex" (one-way aka mono-directional) audio streaming, and for that, since your question is "is there a device that makes this possible", the answer is "yes, there are presently many and inexpensive devices on the market that do exactly this".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).